# Form Gathering Info from Two Other Forms

Tags: forms, field, ms-access-2013, isnull

I have a form that creates a New Work Order. I want to be able to pull the ClientID from the New Client Form or the Main Menu, whichever is open. However I am not getting the desired results:

I have used `=IIf(IsNull(Forms![New Client]![txtClientID]), Forms![Main Menu]![txtClientID], Forms![New Client]![txtClientID])` in the Default Value of the Control on the New Work Order Form.  I get the correct ID when I go to the form from New Client, but a #Name error when I try to access it from the Main Menu.

**What can I do to make it work?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the form is loaded, for example (you need to add your own error traps):

```
Function IsLoaded(ByVal strFormName As String) As Boolean
Const conObjStateClosed = 0
Const conDesignView = 0

    If SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acForm, strFormName) <> conObjStateClosed Then
        If Forms(strFormName).CurrentView <> conDesignView Then
            IsLoaded = True
        End If
    End If
```

However, it may be easier to use OpenArgs ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845(v=office.15).aspx )

In which case you could say something like:

```
If IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
    MsgBox "No openargs"
Else
    Me.txtClientID = Me.Openargs
End If
```

Or even use Openargs to set the default value.